# Как написать рекурсивную функцию на PostgreSQL с дополнительным условием?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица my_table с иерархической структурой (родитель parent_col). У каждой записи есть признак my_bool (True/False).
Чтобы подсчитать количество всех детей для записи, к примеру, 47, у которых значение my_bool = False, я использую такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE parent_col = 47 and  my_bool IS FALSE
```

С этим всё понятно, запрос очень простой. Но каким образом сделать так, чтобы считало не только прямых детей, но и количество их потомков до тех пор, пока не наткнется на запись, где my_bool IS TRUE.
Т.е., запрос должен быть рекурсивным + с условием.
Можете подсказать, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать? У меня знаний SQL для этого не хватает.
Спасибо

Comment: [WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). *Можете подсказать, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать? У меня знаний SQL для этого не хватает.* Вам это задание дали именно для того, чтобы знания появились. А от того, что кто-то за Вас его решит, знаний точно не добавится.

Comment: Естественно, не добавится. Но это не мое основное направление деятельности. Я столкнулся с проблемой, которую мне нужно решить сейчас, и, к сожалению,на данном этапе самостоятельно разобраться не получается. Поэтому и обратился за помощью к сообществу

Answer (score 2):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id) AS
( SELECT id                     -- выбрать детей "1 уровня"
      FROM my_table 
      WHERE parent_col = 47 
        AND my_bool IS FALSE
UNION ALL
  SELECT my_table.id            -- выбрать детей "следующего" уровня
      FROM my_table 
      JOIN cte ON my_table.parent_col = cte.id 
      WHERE my_table.my_bool IS FALSE 
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cte 
LIMIT 100                       -- на всякий случай - а вдруг имеются "петли"?
;
```